# Solr Interfaces

Tags: java, .net, apache, interface, solr

are there any other interfaces, which I can use to index data, as HTTP?

I've got a huge anmount of files to index, which would take lots of time.

I could write POST Clients, but I don't want to use HTTP to give Solr the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure there are lots of interfaces to index data. You might start reading about the topic "Data Import Handler" within [the Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) or [the reference manual](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler).